# javascript slider opacity effect on main image after a click on a thumbnail

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to create a smooth opacity change on this javascript slider when the main image appears after clicking on the correspondig thumbnail. 
I guess it has something to do with the javascript calling the css code when there is a "onclick", but my skills in javascript make me understand the logic but I can't create it myself so far which is quite frustrating.

I already added an opacity animation on my css file hoping it could be a good start and it actually does the trick with the thumbnails, they get the opacity effect when I circulate between them with the arrow keys.

But I haven't managed to do it on the main image when it is changed by clicking on a thumbnail or with the left/right arrow keys. Could anyone help me to answer this question?

```js
var lastImg = 'image1'; //Set initial thumbnail and preview
document.getElementById('image0').src = document.getElementById(lastImg).src;
document.getElementById(lastImg).className = "thumb selected";

function preview(img) {
  document.getElementById(lastImg).className = "thumb normal";
  img.className = "thumb selected";
  document.getElementById('image0').src = img.src;
  lastImg = img.id;
}

function previewOnKey(e) {
  /* left key */
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    var previousImg = document.getElementById(lastImg).previousElementSibling;
    if (previousImg) {
      preview(previousImg);
    }
  }

  /* right key */
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    var nextImg = document.getElementById(lastImg).nextElementSibling;
    if (nextImg) {
      preview(nextImg);
    }
  }
}

document.onkeydown = previewOnKey;
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(../images/vagues.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 1% 75%;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 6px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

.nom {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 3/8;
  grid-row: 1;
  color: #f9423ab5;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 3.2vw;
  align-self: center;
  animation: couleur 8s;
}

a {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
}

.accueil {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 10;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.contact {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 11;
  grid-row: 1;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: coral;
}

.bigimage {
  width: 61vw;
  grid-column: 3/11;
  grid-row: 2/5;
  margin-top: 16px;
  animation: opacity 2s;
}

.thumb {
  width: 3vw;
  height: 2vw;
  margin-left: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  align-self: center;
}

.thumb:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.thumbnails {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 2/5;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.normal {}

.selected {
  animation: opacity 2s;
}

@keyframes opacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="image0" class="preview normal bigimage" />

<div class="thumbnails">
  <img id="image1" class="thumb normal" src="https://placekitten.com/g/150/80" alt="image1" onclick="preview(this)" />
  <img id="image2" class="thumb normal" src="https://placekitten.com/g/151/80" alt="image2" onclick="preview(this)" />
  <img id="image3" class="thumb normal" src="https://placekitten.com/g/152/80" alt="image3" onclick="preview(this)" />

</div>
```

Comment: Hello Rachel, first thanks for you help and corrections with the english formulation of my question, I don't speak english as fluently as I wished. I'm adding the css right now.

Comment: Why are you using an empty 'normal' class? Fill it or remove it - it's cluttering your code. Also you haven't listed a class called preview in your css?

Comment: If you are open to jquery (recommended), fadeIn and fadeOut are very handy for writing quick smooth transitions

Comment: Thanks Rachel, "to clutter" I didn't know this verb in english. I'd rather use only javascript for 2 reasons. The first is that I like to understand what I'm doing and I find it more instructive begining with javascript than going straight to jquerry. What's more I know that the site I'm building will be used in areas where the internet is quite slow, so if I want to spare time to those users, I guess it's better not  loading jquerry files for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

First, remove `animation:opacity 2s;` from the `.bigimage` CSS class. Animations only occur once for each time the animation is applied to an object. Having the `animation:opacity 2s;` applied to the preview image means that the animation occurs when the page loads, but does not occur again.

Secondly, Add the following code the your `preview` method:

```
document.getElementById('image0').className = "preview normal bigimage";
// Force the browser to "redraw" the element.
void document.getElementById('image0').offsetWidth;
document.getElementById('image0').className = "preview normal bigimage selected";
```

This removes the `selected` CSS class from the preview and then re-adds the `selected` CSS class, "waiting" for an animation frame.

```js
var lastImg = "image1"; //Set initial thumbnail and preview
document.getElementById('image0').src = document.getElementById(lastImg).src;
document.getElementById(lastImg).className = "thumb selected";

function preview(img) {
  document.getElementById(lastImg).className = "thumb normal";
  img.className = "thumb selected";
  document.getElementById('image0').src = img.src;
  document.getElementById('image0').className = "preview normal bigimage";
  // Force the browser to "redraw" the element.
  void document.getElementById('image0').offsetWidth;
  document.getElementById('image0').className = "preview normal bigimage selected";
  lastImg = img.id;
}

function previewOnKey(e) {
    /* left key */
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        var previousImg = document.getElementById(lastImg).previousElementSibling;
        if (previousImg) {
            preview(previousImg);
        }
    }

    /* right key */
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        var nextImg = document.getElementById(lastImg).nextElementSibling;
        if (nextImg) {
            preview(nextImg);
        }
    }
}

document.onkeydown = previewOnKey;
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(../images/vagues.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 1% 75%;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 6px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

.nom {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 3/8;
  grid-row: 1;
  color: #f9423ab5;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 3.2vw;
  align-self: center;
  animation: couleur 8s;
}

a {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
}

.accueil {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 10;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.contact {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 11;
  grid-row: 1;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: coral;
}

.bigimage {
  width: 61vw;
  grid-column: 3/11;
  grid-row: 2/5;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.thumb {
  width: 3vw;
  height: 2vw;
  margin-left: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  align-self: center;
}

.thumb:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.thumbnails {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 2/5;
  margin-top: 16px;
}
 
.normal {
  
}
 
.selected {
  animation:opacity 2s;
  
}



@keyframes opacity {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<img id="image0" class="preview normal bigimage" />

<div class="thumbnails">
  <img id="image1" class="thumb normal" src="https://placekitten.com/g/150/80" alt="image1" onclick="preview(this)"/>
  <img id="image2" class="thumb normal" src="https://placekitten.com/g/151/80" alt="image2" onclick="preview(this)" />
  <img id="image3" class="thumb normal" src="https://placekitten.com/g/152/80" alt="image3" onclick="preview(this)" />
 
</div>






</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello "S.Walker" and thanks for your answer. I did what you recommended me to do, but actually even if I changed the CSS and added the code you sent to my javascript, nothing changes, it behaves just as if I hadn't changed anything.

Comment: If you click "Run code snippet" at the bottom of my answer, does that work correctly? - Also, What browser are you using?

Comment: Actually it works in Chrome and Safari but doesn't in firefox, I don't know why because I've already seen css opacity animations in Firefox.

Comment: It doesn't work on the "run code snippet" here, It works for the first image and the second but after it doesn't anymore. I changed browser to check if it was the reason, but I add the same result on chrome as in firefox.

Comment: I updated my answer. I replaced `window.setTimeout...` with `void document.getElementById('image0').offsetWidth;` as according to :https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

Comment: Thank you very much "S. Walker" for the time you spent answering and finding solutions, it works pretty well now :-)). Thanks for the link also it will help me learning more. I changed the css opacity and have a softer transition exactly as  I expected, so cool, thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to post this solution for a [pure javascript slider](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/cefbz89n/). It doesn't include your images, it's just an alternative "slide" rather than "onclick" solution. Even if you don't use it, it may be helpful for you to examine/understand the javascript.

Do try to keep your HTML and CSS tidy- omit needless classes from your HTML and delete empty or unused ones from your CSS file. Your site will run thank you for the optimisations! :)

Hope this helps

```js
//slide and change opacity
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
.mySlides {
  text-align:center;
  display: none;
}

/* Slideshow container */

img {
  width: 350px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  margin-top:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.text {
  color: green;
  display: block;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img id="image1" src="https://placekitten.com/g/150/80" alt="image1" onclick="preview(this)" />
 
    <div class="text">kitten 1</div>
    <div class="dot"><!--img class="thumb normal" onclick="preview(this)"/ alt="1/3"-->1/3</div>

  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img id="image2" src="https://placekitten.com/g/151/80" alt="image2" />
    <div class="text">kitten 2</div>
     <div class="dot"><!--img class="thumb normal" onclick="preview(this)"/ alt="2/3"-->2/3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
   
    <img id="image3" src="https://placekitten.com/g/152/80" alt="image3" onclick="preview(this)" />
    <div class="text">kitten 3</div>
     <div class="dot"><!--img class="thumb normal" onclick="preview(this)"/ alt="3/3"-->3/3</div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rachel, I didn't know stackoverflow before and I find it incredible that people like you spare some time to explain to others what they know in such a kind and complet way. Of course it will help me to understand the Javascript and build my sites. I keep this slider in my pocket for another page, ;-).

Comment: @Guillaume13 Good stuff. Glad to help.  (you can upvote many answers though ;) ) .. Welcome to the stack.. hours of fun!